# Accessing PHP functions that are in an iFrame from parent document

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

So I am trying to access a PHP function, from the parent HTML document, that is in an iFrame which is loaded with a remote PHP file.  The whole reason that I am doing it this way, is because I am using goDaddys Website Builder, which does not allow a user to upload PHP scripts.  So I uploaded a PHP file for testing on my own FTP and was able to access the PHP file by linking the src of the iFrame to the URL of the PHP file on my FTP server.

So far I am just testing to see if this will even work, so the function right now is very simple.

Here is the html:

```
<iframe id="targetFrame" src="http://terrefhosting.net/arcpickup/test.php" style="width: 90%;    height: 300px;"></iframe>
<input onclick="alert('test0'); phpFunction();" type="button" value="Click me"></input>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function phpFunction(){
  alert("test1");
  alert(document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.mailReceipt());
  alert("test2");
}
```

Here is the code in my php file:

```
<?php

function mailReceipt(){
  return "test";
}

?>
```

When I click the button that runs phpFunction onClick,  I get up to alert ("test1"); which means to me that this line in the javascript is failing:

```
alert(document.getElementById('targetFrame').contentWindow.mailReceipt());
```

Comment: your mixing your js and php, iframe or not, you can't call a php function from js

Comment: There is difference between ***client-side*** & ***server-side***.You cannot call serverside functions using clientside script

Comment: Also trying to 'hack' around a host restriction is a terrible idea, when moving hosts is so easy; and godaddy is the worst host on the planet

Comment: +1 @Splntr Not sure why you were down voted for not knowing about everything available in the world. This question is helpful for others to know of capabilities. I also added your solution since someone rejected your edit. Can't get a break can you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/ajax). When a user causes an event to be triggered your Javascript uses the [XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest) to send the request to your server.

Then another Javascript function or event gives a place to work with the server output.

*
The OP provided solution:

```
onclick = loadXMLDoc(); 

function loadXMLDoc() {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else { // code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
 {
    document.getElementById("targetFrame").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
 }
}
 var url = "http://******hosting.net/arcpickup/test.php";
 xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true);
 xmlhttp.send();
}
```

php:

```
<?php
echo "test";
?>
```

Comment: you're explaining calculus to an elementary kid, saying you can't have negative sqrt is far easier